# Text width does not adjust for console width and code is not visible anymore in Spyder4

Tags: anaconda, ide, spyder

I just downloaded Spyder 4. The IDE's look and feel are nice.
However, there is one thing that I don't like about it. When adjusting the width of the right-side panel (variable explorer and the console), the code in my text editor on the left doesn't adjust accordingly.

This causes my code to not be visible anymore whenever the right side is pulled over it (my picture below makes it clearer what I mean).

Is there a setting in Python to change this?

[image]

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) You need to use the horizontal scrollbar at the bottom of the editor to access the content of those lines that overflow to the right. Is not there for you?

Comment: Hi Carlos, yes it is and I can also go there with my pointer. However, that requires me to scroll to the right/go there manually, which can be a bit inconvenient. Instead, I would find it easier if the hidden content were to be shown on a new (/extended) line.